# Where are Pey'j's shoes and desk?

Tags: beyond-good-and-evil

If anybody remembers playing *Beyond Good & Evil* a while ago, maybe you can help me.

I've just finished going through the Slaughterhouses, and am now told that I need to find the ship that Pey'j hid somewhere on the Home island.  I've found the two hidden consoles beneath the boards depicting blueprints for Pey'j's Jet Boots, but I don't have the codes.  Various elements seem to suggest that the codes are what was written on the bottom of Pey'j's shoes earlier in the game.

---

Upon reviewing my collection of Mdisks, I recalled that during the factory mission, a security camera picked up footage of the captive Pey'j.  A guard mentioned that his jacket and shoes had been confiscated, and placed in "*The Locker*".  However, when I returned to the factory, I found myself unable to find my way to any kind of locker at all.  How do I get Pey'j's shoes back?  Was this something I was required to do during my first visit to the Factory, before destroying the elevator, thus rendering it inoperable in future visits?  Did I somehow miss them, and now cannot complete the game?

In addition, the message given to Jade on an Mdisk indicated that "*Check-Up*" information regarding the *Beluga* (the ship) can be found on his desk.  Where is this desk?  I've been all over the Home Island with no success.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, although this question is tagged 'spoiler', I am **not** asking for the codes themselves, merely how to proceed in the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needed to pick them up whilst still in the factory. Sorry

They should be right after you find the Mdisk

His desk will be under the lighthouse, although I suspect they will be on the walls with the blueprints.

Comment: If you can't get back,  I think the codes change on every file, so load an old save

Comment: It turns out I already had them anyway, but thanks for the heads up, and thanks about the desk.  :P